# Scaling is blurry when animating using transition

Tags: html, css

I want to scale some text on hover, however, during the animation, the text appears blurry (although quite hard to see). How can I prevent the blurriness?

https://jsfiddle.net/vt7yxhcw/8/

**HTML:**

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="title">LogoTest</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  font-family: "Bitter";
  margin: 100px;
}

.title {
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: white;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.title:hover {
  transform: scale(0.96);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/vt7yxhcw/10/

**changed CSS**

```
.title {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  transform: perspective(1px) scale(0.99999) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
}

.title:hover {
  transform: perspective(1px) scale(0.96) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
}
```

I added an initial scale slightly less than 1 (not recognizable) to have the browser initially rendering a scaling. Adding `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` is for preventing blurry subpixel smoothing. Adding `translate3d( 0, 0, 0)` gives a little initial blurryness but smoothes the transition blur a bit too. The `perspective()` gives an element some pseudo 3D depth, so the browser uses some other algorithms for rendering - which in my experience also reduces overall blur.

You won't be able to disable the blur at all, but using it like that reduces it to a minimum. It's just how the browsers are rendering the pixel calculations.

Comment: This seems to not only blur it during the animation, but the blur appears to stay active once the animation is over.

Comment: That's because of the `perspective()`. But removing it would result in a huge blur-sharp difference again.